# Solve $(2z-1)^5 - i = 0$ for $z$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Can someone solve $(2z-1)^5 - i = 0$ for $z$ and explain every step in detail?

I have seen multiple vague explanations for the solution, but I haven't managed to understand them well enough.

I've tried solving this question myself, and this is what I've managed to do:

$(2z-1)^5 -i = 0$

$32z^5-1 -i = 0$

$32z^5 = 1+i$

$z^5 = 1/32 * 1+i$

$z^5 = \sqrt{2}/32 \text{ cis }(\pi/4 + 2k\pi)$

$r^5 = \sqrt{2}/32 => r=\sqrt[10]{2}/2$

$5\theta = \text{ cis }(\pi/4 + 2k\pi) => \theta = \text{ cis }(\pi/20 + 2k\pi/5)$

$ z = \sqrt[10]{2}/2\text{ cis }(\pi/20 + 2k\pi/5)$

After seeing other solutions, I believe my answer is wrong. Could someone point out my mistake and help me fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You have made an error in the very first step, because $$(a+b)^5 \ne a^5 + b^5.$$

Comment: You would expect five solutions.  One is obvious if you see $(2z-1)^5 -i = 0 \implies (2z-1)^5 =i = i^5$ and the others are based on other fifth roots of $i$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's wrong since $(2z-1)^5\ne32z^5-1$.

Note that $i=\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac\pi2\right)$. So, the fifth roots of $i$ are the numbers of the form $\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac\pi{10}+\frac{2k\pi}5\right)$, with $k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. So, the solutions of your equation are the numbers of the form$$\frac12\left(\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac\pi{10}+\frac{2k\pi}5\right)+1\right)\quad\text{($k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}$)}.$$

Comment: Why is $\sqrt[5]{i} = cis(\pi/10 + 2k\pi/5)$?

Comment: Because\begin{align}\left(\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac\pi{10}+\frac{2k\pi}5\right)\right)^5&=\operatorname{cis}\left(5\left(\frac\pi{10}+\frac{2k\pi}5\right)\right)\\&=\operatorname{cis}\left(\frac\pi2+2k\pi\right)\\&=i.\end{align}